# asp.net mvc 4: SqlServerSpatial110.dll error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i'm using MVC4 and EF5 CodeFirst in my project. I can select records from DB , but when i'm try'ing to create new one i get this error:

> Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This error occures in my Hosting and in localhost it works correctly.
Even i added this dll from my system32 to my project and use below code to say the engin to use the dll from my bin:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

But it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the properties of SqlServerSpatial110.dll to “Copy to Output directory = Copy always”? Based on the error I assume that this specific dll doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: I did, when i publish it copies to bin folder. I use sqlserver 2012 on my localhost and in Hosting

Comment: did you checked the version of the SQL Server CLR Types which is installed on the server? Maybe you have a 64 bits server and the version installed is 32 bits. Or maybe the target of your solution is different than the type of the server:)

Comment: i asked server supporting team to check if this is dll exists on server's system32 or system64. but they told we can't install it on Host. so i have to put the dll in my bin folder...

Comment: Another idea/remark: the SqlServerSpatial110.dll is an unmanaged library. Maybe is a good idea to see what the location of this library should be:)

Comment: thank you for considering. I Resolved it by Updating my EF5 to EF6... :)

Comment: wow...that's so random...:). I am happy to hear that you solved it. Sorry I couldn't help you:)